# Get the parent product categories ids from a sub product category ID in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

```
For example : 
- A = 21
  - B = 22
     - C = 23
```

How can I get 21 and 22 IDs using 23 sub Id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated (2020)**

To get the parent terms Ids from a product category term ID, try the following *(code is commented)*:

```
// Get the parent term slugs list
$parent_terms_list = get_term_parents_list( 23, 'product_cat', array('format' => 'slug', 'separator' => ',', 'link' => false, 'inclusive' => false) );

$parent_terms_ids = []; // Initialising variable

// Loop through parent terms slugs array to convert them in term IDs array
foreach( explode(',', $parent_terms_list) as $term_slug ){
    if( ! empty($term_slug) ){
        // Get the term ID from the term slug and add it to the array of parent terms Ids
        $parent_terms_ids[] = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, 'product_cat' )->term_id;
    }
}

// Test output of the raw array (just for testing)
print_r($parent_terms_ids);
```

Tested and works.

---

**Addition:**

You can better use Wordpress **[`get_ancestors()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_ancestors/)** dedicated function, like in [this recent answer thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61345614/get-top-level-parent-product-category-as-body-class-in-woocommerce/61346817#61346817) or on [those other related answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bwoocommerce%5d%20get_ancestors()).

In this case the code is going to be:

```
// Get the parent term ids array
$parent_terms_ids = $parent_ids = get_ancestors( $child_id, 'product_cat' , 'taxonomy');  

// Test output of the raw array (just for testing)
print_r($parent_terms_ids);
```

Related treads:

- [woocommerce - How do I get the most top level category of the current product category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20777929/woocommerce-how-do-i-get-the-most-top-level-category-of-the-current-product-ca/20778095#20778095)
- [Get top level parent product category as body class in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61345614/get-top-level-parent-product-category-as-body-class-in-woocommerce/61346817#61346817)
- [List product categories hierarchy from a product id in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53312319/list-product-categories-hierarchy-from-a-product-id-in-woocommerce/53320088#53320088)

**Related documented Wordpress functions:**

- Documented Wordpress function [`get_term_parents_list()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_parents_list/)
- Documented Wordpress function [`get_term_by()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_by/)
- Documented Wordpress function [`get_ancestors()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_ancestors/)

Comment: Wow Thank you, Working fine :)



I also worked on bellow function and It's working fine :)

function parentIDs($sub_category_id)
{
 static $parent_ids = [];  
 if ( $sub_category_id != 0 ) {
  $category_parent = get_term( $sub_category_id, 'product_cat' );    
  $parent_ids[] = $category_parent->term_id;
  parentIDs($category_parent->parent);
 } 
 return $parent_ids;
}
$sub_category_id = 23;
$parent_ids_array = parentIDs($sub_category_id);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($parent_ids_array);
echo "</pre>";

Answer (score 0):

```
function parentIDs($sub_category_id)
{
    static $parent_ids = [];        
    if ( $sub_category_id != 0 ) {
        $category_parent = get_term( $sub_category_id, 'product_cat' );             
        $parent_ids[] = $category_parent->term_id;
        parentIDs($category_parent->parent);
    } 
    return $parent_ids;
}
$sub_category_id = 23;
$parent_ids_array = parentIDs($sub_category_id);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($parent_ids_array);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to get the parents ids is to use the built in function given and documented by Wordpress. See [get_ancestors](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_ancestors/)

if you have checked [get_term_parents_list](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.4/src/wp-includes/category-template.php#L1335) you will see that it uses [get_ancestors](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_ancestors/) see this link
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.4/src/wp-includes/category-template.php#L1362

So the short answer is just below code.

```
$parent_ids = get_ancestors( $child_id, 'product_cat' , 'taxonomy');
```