# Add category & subcategory to packing slip wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I am looking for a line of code to add to this template to display the category and subcategory of the product each time.

If possible, it would be nice to have somewhere to put a title above it as well.

````
<?php 
/**
 * Packing Slips template
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/xc-woo-google-cloud-print/packing-slip.php.
 *
 *
 * @author      XpertsClub
 * @package     WoocommerceGoogleCloudPrint/Templates
 * @version     2.8
 */

do_action( 'xc_woo_cloud_print_before_document', $this->type, $this->order ); ?>
<?php
      if(in_array($this->settings['size'],array("A8"))){
          ?>
          <div class="small-header">
          <?php
        if( $this->has_header_logo() ) {
            $this->header_logo();
        } else {
            echo apply_filters( 'xc_woo_cloud_print_packing_slip_title', __( 'Packing Slip', XC_WOO_CLOUD ) );
        }
        ?>

        <div class="shop-name"><h3><?php $this->shop_name(); ?></h3></div>
            <div class="shop-address"><?php $this->shop_address(); ?></div>
      </div>  
          <?php  
      }else{
      ?> 
<table class="head container">
    <tr>
        <td class="header">
        <?php
        if( $this->has_header_logo() ) {
            $this->header_logo();
        } else {
            echo apply_filters( 'xc_woo_cloud_print_packing_slip_title', __( 'Packing Slip', XC_WOO_CLOUD ) );
        }
        ?>
        </td>
        <td class="shop-info">
            <div class="shop-name"><h3><?php $this->shop_name(); ?></h3></div>
            <div class="shop-address"><?php $this->shop_address(); ?></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php
      } ?>
<h1 class="document-type-label">
<?php if( $this->has_header_logo() ) echo apply_filters( 'xc_woo_cloud_print_packing_slip_title', __( 'Packing Slip', XC_WOO_CLOUD ) ); ?>
</h1>

<?php do_action( 'xc_woo_cloud_print_after_document_label', $this->type, $this->order ); ?>

<table class="order-data-addresses">
    <tr>

        <?php if($this->settings['packing-slip_shipping_billing_layout'] == "billing-shipping"){ ?>
            <td class="address billing-address">
                <?php if ( $this->settings['packing-slip_show_billing'] == 'yes') { ?>
                <h3><?php echo apply_filters('xc_woo_cloud_print_packing_slip_billing_address', __( 'Billing Address:', XC_WOO_CLOUD )); ?></h3>
                <?php $this->billing_address(); ?>
                <?php } ?>
            </td>
        <?php } ?>

        <td class="address shipping-address">
            <h3><?php  echo apply_filters('xc_woo_cloud_print_packing_slip_shipping_address', __( 'Shipping Address:', XC_WOO_CLOUD )); ?></h3>
            <?php $this->shipping_address(); ?>
            <?php if ( $this->settings['packing-slip_show_email'] == 'yes' ) { ?>
            <div class="billing-email"><?php $this->billing_email(); ?></div>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if ( $this->settings['packing-slip_show_phone'] == 'yes' ) { ?>
            <div class="billing-phone"><?php $this->billing_phone(); ?></div>
            <?php } ?>
        </td>
        <?php if($this->settings['packing-slip_shipping_billing_layout'] == "shipping-billing"){ ?>
        <td class="address billing-address">
            <?php if ( $this->settings['packing-slip_show_billing'] == 'yes') { ?>
            <h3><?php echo apply_filters('xc_woo_cloud_print_packing_slip_billing_address', __( 'Billing Address:', XC_WOO_CLOUD )); ?></h3>
            <?php $this->billing_address(); ?>
            <?php } ?>
        </td>
        <?php } ?>
         <?php
      if(in_array($this->settings['size'],array("A6","A7","A8"))){
            echo '</tr>';  
            echo '</table>';  
      }
      ?>
  <?php if(!in_array($this->settings['size'],array("A6","A7","A8"))){ ?>  <td class="order-data" > <?php } ?>
        <table class="order-data-table">
                <?php do_action( 'xc_woo_cloud_print_before_order_data', $this->type, $this->order ); ?>
                <tr class="order-number">
                    <th><?php _e( 'Order Number:', XC_WOO_CLOUD ); ?></th>
                    <td><?php $this->order_number(); ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="order-date">
                    <th><?php _e( 'Order Date:', XC_WOO_CLOUD ); ?></th>
                    <td><?php $this->order_date(); ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="shipping-method">
                    <th><?php _e( 'Shipping Method:', XC_WOO_CLOUD ); ?></th>
                    <td><?php $this->shipping_method(); ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php if($this->settings['packing-slip_show_payment_method'] == "yes") { ?>
                <tr class="shipping-method">
                    <th><?php _e( 'Payment Method:', XC_WOO_CLOUD ); ?></th>
                    <td><?php $this->payment_method(); ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>

                <?php do_action( 'xc_woo_cloud_print_before_barcode', $this->type, $this->order ); ?>

                 <?php if($this->settings['packing-slip_show_barcode'] == "yes"){ ?>
                <tr class="shipping-method">
                    <td colspan="2" align="center" style="padding:5px;">
                    <img alt="Code" src="<?php echo $this->get_barcode();?>" /></td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>


                <?php do_action( 'xc_woo_cloud_print_after_order_data', $this->type, $this->order ); ?>
            </table>            
        <?php if(!in_array($this->settings['size'],array("A6","A7","A8"))){ ?>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<?php } ?>

<?php do_action( 'xc_woo_cloud_print_before_order_details', $this->type, $this->order ); ?>

<table class="order-details">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="product"><?php _e('Product', XC_WOO_CLOUD ); ?></th>
            <th class="quantity"><?php _e('Quantity', XC_WOO_CLOUD ); ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php $items = $this->get_order_items(); if( sizeof( $items ) > 0 ) : foreach( $items as $item_id => $item ) : ?>
        <tr class="<?php echo apply_filters( 'xc_woo_cloud_print_item_row_class', $item_id, $this->type, $this->order, $item_id ); ?> <?php echo (in_array($this->settings['size'],array("A6","A7","A8")))?"no-bottom-border":"";?>">
            <td class="product">
                <span class="item-name"><?php echo $item['name']; ?></span>
                <?php if(!in_array($this->settings['size'],array("A6","A7","A8"))){ ?>
                <?php do_action( 'xc_woo_cloud_print_before_item_meta', $this->type, $item, $this->order  ); ?>
                <span class="item-meta"><?php echo $item['meta']; ?></span>
                <dl class="meta">
                    <?php if( !empty( $item['sku'] ) ) : ?><dt class="sku"><?php _e( 'SKU:', XC_WOO_CLOUD ); ?></dt><dd class="sku"><?php echo $item['sku']; ?></dd><?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if( !empty( $item['weight'] ) ) : ?><dt class="weight"><?php _e( 'Weight:', XC_WOO_CLOUD ); ?></dt><dd class="weight"><?php echo $item['weight']; ?><?php echo get_option('woocommerce_weight_unit'); ?></dd><?php endif; ?>
                </dl>
                <?php do_action( 'xc_woo_cloud_print_after_item_meta', $this->type, $item, $this->order  ); ?>
                <?php } ?>
            </td>
            <td class="quantity <?php echo (absint($item['quantity']) > 1)?"more":"";?>"><?php echo $item['quantity']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php if(in_array($this->settings['size'],array("A6","A7","A8"))){ ?>
        <tr class="no-top-border">
        <td colspan="2">
        <?php do_action( 'xc_woo_cloud_print_before_item_meta', $this->type, $item, $this->order  ); ?>
        <span class="item-meta"><?php echo $item['meta']; ?></span>
        <dl class="meta">
            <?php if( !empty( $item['sku'] ) ) : ?><dt class="sku"><?php _e( 'SKU:', XC_WOO_CLOUD ); ?></dt><dd class="sku"><?php echo $item['sku']; ?></dd><?php endif; ?>
            <?php if( !empty( $item['weight'] ) ) : ?><dt class="weight"><?php _e( 'Weight:', XC_WOO_CLOUD ); ?></dt><dd class="weight"><?php echo $item['weight']; ?><?php echo get_option('woocommerce_weight_unit'); ?></dd><?php endif; ?>
        </dl>
        <?php do_action( 'xc_woo_cloud_print_after_item_meta', $this->type, $item, $this->order  ); ?>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php endforeach; endif; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>

<?php do_action( 'xc_woo_cloud_print_after_order_details', $this->type, $this->order ); ?>

<?php do_action( 'xc_woo_cloud_print_before_customer_notes', $this->type, $this->order ); ?>
<div class="customer-notes">
    <?php if ( $this->get_shipping_notes() ) : ?>
        <h3><?php _e( 'Customer Notes', XC_WOO_CLOUD ); ?></h3>
        <?php $this->shipping_notes(); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php do_action( 'xc_woo_cloud_print_after_customer_notes', $this->type, $this->order ); ?>

<?php if ( $this->get_footer() ): ?>
<div id="footer">
    <?php $this->footer(); ?>
</div><!-- #letter-footer -->
<?php endif; ?>

<?php do_action( 'xc_woo_cloud_print_after_document', $this->type, $this->order ); ?>```
````

Answer (score 0):

1) Take a code from this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/53320088/6364829 and put it into your functions.php
2) Place this code where you want to display categories:

```
echo do_shortcode("[product_cat_list id='$item_id']");
```

Comment: I did both, but nothing showing it just shows plain text, so I've added <?php in front and now only shows '' is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Can you add a piece of code where you trying to display categories?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you want me to do if I am honest. I tried pasting that linked code into my functions, then put that single link you suggested at the bottom of the template within the plugin, and it came up with "" without any category. Sorry as you can probably tell I'm not confident with this as my knowledge is paper thin.

Comment: You have to put `<?php echo do_shortcode("[product_cat_list id='$item_id']"); ?>`  after `<?php $items = $this->get_order_items(); if( sizeof( $items ) > 0 ) : foreach( $items as $item_id => $item ) : ?>`   but before   `<?php endforeach; endif; ?>`