# How to get the correct category hierarchy in a subcategory

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I can't get the correct hierarchy of the category I'm in. Now with the help of the code I managed to get the previous category, but I want to get the full hierarchy of categories.

Hierarchy on the site for example:

1. Mazda
2. 6
3. GH
4. 2008
5. Sedan

Being in the Sedan subcategory, I want to get the full path in the page name: Mazda 6 GH 2008 Sedan, now I see it like this: Sedan

I have found so far only a way to get the previous category: 2008 going before Sedan.

```
    $terms = get_the_terms($product->ID, 'product_cat');
      foreach ($terms as $term) {

        $product_cat = $term->name;
           echo $product_cat;
             break;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are using woo-commerce but you can check out this answer,It can help you with your query

answerhttps://stackoverflow.com/a/53320088/15246736